# How to render user's checked checkboxes from MongoDB database using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using this form to get requests from the users.

```ejs
<%- include("header") -%>

    <div class="box" id="heading">
        <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
            <form action="/delete" method="post">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="item-p">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= item.checkedValue %>" onclick="this.form.submit(); checkedif();">
                        <input type="hidden" name="checkedItemId" value="<%= item._id %>"></input>
                        <p><%= item.name %></p>
                    </div>
                    <div><button type="submit" name="deleteIcon" value="<%= item._id %>"><i class="uil uil-trash-alt delete-icon"></i></button></div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="listName" value="<%= listTitle %>"></input>
            </form>
        <% }) %>

        <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
            <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <script>  
        function checkedif() {
            const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='checkbox']");
            checkboxes.forEach((checkbox)=>{
                if(checkbox.value === "On"){
                    checkbox.checked = true;
                    console.log("checkedif");
                } else {
                    checkbox.checked = false;
                }
            })
            };
    </script>
    <%- include("footer") -%>
```

I can save the inputs in the database using this route:

```ejs
app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
    
    const deleteItemId = req.body.deleteIcon;
    const listName = req.body.listName;
    const checkedItemId = req.body.checkedItemId;
    const checkboxCurrentStaus = req.body.checkbox;
    const day = date.getDate();

    console.log("hidden value: " + checkedItemId);
    console.log("current status: " + checkboxCurrentStaus);
    //console.log(deleteItemId);
    
    if(deleteItemId){

        if(listName === day) {
            Item.findByIdAndRemove(deleteItemId)
          .then(function () {
            console.log("Successfully deleted the item from DB!");
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
    
            res.redirect("/");
        } else {
            List.findOneAndUpdate({name: listName}, {$pull: {items: {_id: deleteItemId}}})
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Successfully deleted the item from " + listName + " list!");
              })
              .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
              });
    
            res.redirect("/lists/" + listName);
        }   

    } else {
        if(checkboxCurrentStaus === "Off") {
            if(listName === day) {
                Item.updateOne({_id: checkedItemId}, {checkedValue: "On"})
                .then(function () {
                  console.log("Successfully updated 'checked ON' item list");
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                });
            res.redirect("/");
            } else {

                List.listName.findOneAndUpdate({_id: checkedItemId}, {$push: {items: {checkedValue: "On"}}})
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("Successfully updated 'checked ON' "+ checkedItemId + " in the " + listName + " list!");
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            res.redirect("/lists/" + listName);
            }
        } else {
            if(listName === day) {
                Item.updateOne({_id: checkedItemId}, {checkedValue: "Off"})
                .then(function () {
                  console.log("Successfully updated 'checked OFF' item list");
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                });
            res.redirect("/");
            } else {
                List.listName.findOneAndUpdate({_id: checkedItemId}, {$push: {items: {checkedValue: "Off"}}})
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("Successfully updated 'checked ON' "+ checkedItemId + " in the " + listName + " list!");
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            res.redirect("/lists/" + listName);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

But I cannot render the checked checkboxes which the users have previously saved in the database. I have tried to use the mentioned `checkedif()` function but failed. I am using the following style for checked items:

```css
input:checked+input[type="hidden"]+p {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: #A683E3;
}
```